# How much political influence is involved in the academia in Poland?

Tags: phd, politics, habilitation, poland

I heard that Polish national politics influences the appointment of tenured positions in their universities.

E.g. if some party is in power, they would like to see somebody loyal to them as the head of a faculty or even the rector of the university. Also, if someone is loyal to the party in power, his PhD students have better chance of getting into the university and obtain tenure.

I also heard that, even getting a "Habilitation" requires a lot of political backing.

To what extent is it true?

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the former Warsaw-pact states are quite inhomogeneous nowadays and all the problems mentioned before still apply (the situation in Eastern Germany and Hungary is arguably quite different today). You want to know about Poland, so it’s fine to ask about this. Answers about Hungary won’t help you. Polish academia is not so big, so you may have to wait for a while for somebody familiar with it sees this question. You can also add [a bounty](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to attract more attention.